# Concatenating dynamically changing numbers of values

Tags: r, vector, paste

Say I have n individual vectors of values, in this case n=3:

```
V01_max <- 30
V02_max <- 60
V03_max <- 30
```

and I'd like to create a vector,

```
big_max <- c(V01_max, V02_max, V03_max)
```

The issue I'm curious about, is what happens when the number of `Vn_max` values changes? Today it is 3, but tomorrow it could be 12:

```
V01_max <- 30
V02_max <- 60
V03_max <- 30

V04_max <- 33
V05_max <- 39
V06_max <- 15

V07_max <- 5
V08_max <- 5
V09_max <- 36

V10_max <- 9
V11_max <- 9
V12_max <- 9
```

where as now I want

```
big_max <- c(V01_max, V02_max, V03_max, V04_max, V05_max, V06_max, V07_max, V08_max, V09_max, V10_max, V11_max, V12_max)
```

What would be the best approach to pull this out?

Idea #1: am I going to have to use string matching on variable names?
Idea #2: is there some list structure I might need to use?
Idea #3: surely I don't need any fancy 'do.call' or 'apply' functions, correct?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You already seem to be using a vector.  Why do you need to name the V**_max entries?  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm working in with ggplot and using a config file where the user will specify what the maximum value is for however many plots they want generated. The code needs the individual values concatenated at a certain point.

Comment: Maybe with `unlist(mget(ls(pattern='^V\\d+_max$')))`.

Comment: More likely, there's a better way to approach the problem.

Comment: I'm working with what I've got, my friends!